# Selenium Multiple Elements Selection Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to extract all available elements for the Xpath, and I did try element with 's' and without and cant seem to make it work. being 'Element' its alright but only returns me the first result and with 'Elements' it gives me an error : "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements'"

My code :
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

```
url = 'https://automira.ro/dealeri-autorizati/lista'

PATH = 'C:\\Users\\czoca\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.6\\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(url)

driver.maximize_window()# For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(100)# gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

dealers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]')

for dealer in dealers:
    name = dealer.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/h4/a").text
    email = dealer.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/a').text
    phone = dealer.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a').text
    print(name,email,phone)
```

Any ideias?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find_elements method returns a list object. you can iterate on list object to get all the elements you need.

for n in name:
print(n.text)

Comment: I have : for dealer in dealers: to do that. but still wont work..

Comment: I did that and I still get 1 result

Comment: you get 1result because you are using absolute xpath

Comment: or you can add "." in your xpath inside loop which means referencing to your main xpath

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `dealers` returns a list of WebElements, so you can use `find_elements`. But in for loop - `dealer` returns only one WebElement per iteration, so you have to use `find_element`

```
dealers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]') 

for dealer in dealers:
    # you should use 'find_element' for name, email and phone
    name = dealer.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/h4/a").text
    email = dealer.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/a').text
    phone = dealer.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a').text
    print(name,email,phone)
```

Comment: I understand that was my logic, but it still gives me 1 result and there are alot of results available. maybe my xpath is wrong? It is a <div class

Comment: It gives you only one result, because your XPath is same for all the iterations. Can you post the URL?

Comment: https://automira.ro/dealeri-autorizati/lista  here, yes they are equal, but shouldnt it go through each that has the same path? Or maybe is better to tell to look into Class_?

Comment: well, I did something and It work.. I changed the first like to a different path but now i am confused